# Where to download .rpm manually without yum?

Tags: linux, rpm

How can I manually download official .rpm's, is there an official repo? Couldn't find anything useful when googling

Apparently there is an solution to my answer on redhat but I need to pay to see it since it is subscriber exclusive content:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6996

Comment: What "official" means to you? Official to which distribution? Red Hat? Suse? Amazon Linux?

Comment: nonmodified packages = official

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Centos repos:
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

or you can find across various distros here: https://rpmfind.net/